# Nested struct in C issue

Tags: c

I have a struct declaration in C that looks something like this:

```
static struct {
   int a;
   int b;
} myStruct[10];
```

I want to declare a struct member variable inside myStruct, so I try to add this:

```
static struct {
   int c;
   int d;
   struct myStruct[10] s;
} myNestedStruct[100];
```

I'm getting a bunch of errors i.e. `syntax error before or at: [` and 
`syntax requires ";" after last struct/union member`. What would the better way to implement the nested structs be?

EDIT: My code now looks like this:

```
static struct {
   int a;
   int b;
} myStruct[10];

static struct {
   int c;
   int d;
   struct myStruct s[10];
} myNestedStruct[100];
```

However I'm getting an error: `incomplete struct/union/enum myStruct: s`

Comment: Use "struct myStruct  s[10] "in the structure member.

Comment: Modify `struct myStruct[10] s;`  to `struct myStruct s[10];`

Comment: The second struct was slightly edited to add it's name `myNestedStruct[100]`. I made the changes but I got an error which said `incomplete struct/union/enum myStruct: s`

Comment: Neither structure has a tag. In both cases, you are declaring a variable as an anonymous struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `myStruct` first before using it as a struct type.

```
struct myStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

static struct {
    int c;
    int d;
    struct myStruct s[10];
} myNestedStruct[100];
```

This creates a variable called `myNestedStruct` which is an array of 100 structs, each containing two `int`s and an array of 10 `mystruct`s.

Answer (score 2):

When you write code like
`struct { ... } Foo;`, it's not declaring a *type* named `Foo` but a *variable*.  Its type is an anonymous `struct` corresponding to what you put in the curly braces. If you want to declare a type, write `struct Foo { ... };`.

That's where your error is coming from -- `myStruct` is not a type name, so when you write `struct myStruct` in the definition of `myNestedStruct` the compiler thinks you're about to define a struct by that name. But then it encounters an `[` which shouldn't be the next token in a struct declaration ever so it tells you can't make sense of the code.